# Django DetailView: switches me to a different user

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have two user types, a student and a tutor.. and I have this `ListView` of tutors rendering their name, profile headline and bio, which works successfully, and I also put a link to those three fields redirecting to the detailed view of their profile. Now, I used cbv `DetailView` for rendering a detailed view of their profile, which also works fine.. but the only problem is, whenever I click on those link as a student, it switches my profile or my user type to that specific tutor, but when I click home or any pages of the website it switches back to normal. Could someone help me with this, please? Because I have search a solution for this problem since yesterday but I couldn't find a problem that similar to mine. Sorry for my english btw.

This is the list of tutors, and as you can see on the upper right, I am logged in as a student.
[image: This is the list of tutors, and as you can see on the upper right, I am logged in as a student.]

Here, you can see on the upper right that it switches me to joss's profile.
[image: Here, you can see on the upper right that it switches me to joss's profile.]

this is my models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_tutor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=False)
    current_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default_pic.jpg', upload_to=path_and_rename, verbose_name='Profile Pictures')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.username}'


class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='student_profile')
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name} Profile"


class TutorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tutor_profile')
    profile_headline = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    is_validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    DAYS = (('Monday', 'Monday'),
            ('Tuesday', 'Tuesday'),
            ('Wednesday', 'Wednesday'),
            ('Thursday', 'Thursday'),
            ('Friday', 'Friday'),
            ('Saturday', 'Saturday'),
            ('Sunday', 'Sunday'),)

    LANG = (('Javascript', 'Javascript'),
            ('Python', 'Python'),
            ('Swift', 'Swift'),
            ('Java', 'Java'),
            ('Sql', 'Sql'),
            ('PHP', 'PHP'),
            ('C#', 'C#'),)

    programming_languages = MultiSelectField(choices=LANG, null=True)
    availability = MultiSelectField(choices=DAYS, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name} Profile"
```

this is my views

```
class TutorListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'accounts/tutor_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'tutors'
    ordering = ['userrating']
    paginate_by = 5


class TutorDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'accounts/tutor_detail_view.html'


class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'
```

If you guys need more information please let me know..

Comment: after changing the page user is returned or the login user is changed permanently?

Comment: @mrash no, it does not change permanently. And If I click home, it goes back to normal.

Comment: The problem is in your template and your context variables. for example, you are using `user` and in the child template the `user` variable is used for another user

Comment: @mrash oh, that make sense. I have no idea that a simple thing like that could cause problems. Thank you so much, I got it working now, I just put a `context_object_name = 'tutor'` to my `DetailView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `context_object_name = 'tutor'` in your `DetailView` class!